# Coding challenge: index of vowels

Tags: javascript

Hey I am trying to solve this coding challenge.
The problem is that for the input "YoMama" I get the result [1,2,4,4] and not [1,2,4,6]. This is because the letter "a" appears twice in the word "YoMama". Anyone that can help me solving this issue?

I understand that there might be entirely different approaches of solving this, but I would appreciate it if I could just slightly modify my code.

Curious to see what you guys suggest to fix this.

---

The coding challenge:

> We want to know the index of the vowels in a given word, for example,
>   there are two vowels in the word super (the second and fourth
>   letters). So given a string "super", we should return a list of [2,
>   4].
>
> Some examples:
>       Mmmm  => []
>       Super => [2,4]
>       Apple => [1,5]
>       YoMama -> [1,2,4,6]
>
> ```
> NOTE: Vowels in this context refers to English Language Vowels - a e i o u y 
> NOTE: this is indexed from [1..n] (not zero indexed!)
> ```

---

```js
function vowelIndices(word) {
  let oldarr = word.toLowerCase().split("")
  console.log(oldarr)
  let newarr = word.toLowerCase().match(/[aeiouy]/g)
  console.log(newarr)
  let finalarr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < oldarr.length; j++) {
      if (newarr[i] === oldarr[j]) {
        finalarr.push(oldarr.indexOf(newarr[i]) + 1)
        break
      }
    }
  }
  return finalarr
}


vowelIndices("YoMama")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop of each character of the word and check if it is vowel by matching against an array of vowel strings. If a match is found, store the index (+1 because the index should be 1 based as per the challenge requirements).

```js
var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

function vowelIndices(word) {
  var foundIndexes = [];

  /* Loop each character in the word */
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  
    /** Check if the character is found in array of vowels */
    if (vowels.indexOf(word[i].toLowerCase()) > -1) {
    
      /* Found a match, store the index (+1) */
      foundIndexes.push(i + 1);
    }
  }

  return foundIndexes;
}

console.log('Mmmm', vowelIndices('Mmmm'));
console.log('Super', vowelIndices('Super'));
console.log('Apple', vowelIndices('Apple'));
console.log('YoMama', vowelIndices('YoMama'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use spread operator.

```js
const str = "Apple";
const vow = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
const result = [];
[...str.toLowerCase()].forEach((char, index) => {
  if (vow.includes(char)) {
    result.push(index + 1);
  }
})

console.log(result)
```